# A fellowship of nine words

Tags: pattern, word-sequence

I am talking about a set of uncapitalized, everyday English words, each
with five or more letters that all share a certain property.
There are only **nine words** in Merriam-Webster that have this property:

> shire, washing, color, aware, carol, connect, virgin, ??????, ??????

What are the two missing words?
(Remember: Only English words with at least five letters. Only uncapitalized
words. Only words that show up in Merriam-Webster)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The missing words are

> florid, sylvan

because they have the property that

> they are part of U.S. state names. The words can't be full words of state names, otherwise we'd have island, north, south and jersey, too. A tenth word might be "strict", if you count the District of Columbia.

(I think one could argue whether the missing words are really

> "everyday"

words.)

Comment: I just found an article that uses one of the missing words.... An hour or two after seeing this answer come up. And I almost spoiled your spoiler doing so.

Answer (score 6):

@M Oehm is correct as to what the answers are, and that all answers

> are part of state names. Confirm it for yourself in the list below (hidden by spoiler).

Here are the words in context:

> New Hamp**shire**,
>  **Washing**ton,
>  **Color**ado,
>  Del**aware**, 
>  North/South **Carol**ina,
>  **Connect**icut,
>  **Virgin**ia,
>  **Florid**a,
>  Penn**sylvan**ia

Hope this helps!